# Firefox does not show up when launching Selenium Java application

Tags: java, selenium, firefox, geckodriver

I am new to Selenium.

I wrote this simple code:

```
    System.setProperty("webdriver.firefox.bin",
            "C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Mozilla Firefox\\firefox.exe");

    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\location\\geckodriver.exe");

    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.stackexchange.com");
    driver.quit();
```

The code seems to work, no errors stop the execution, but nothing pops up.
Can somebody figure it out?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try below solution without setProperty for firefox.exe

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "C:\\location\\geckodriver.exe");
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();       
driver.get("http://www.stackexchange.com");
```

Comment: @sirdan : please check and accept my answer once you confirm from your end